# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.datetimepicker.js:1619(anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, datetimepicker

I try to use jquery.datetimepicker in my Symfony 2.7 project but when I call datetimepicker in my view not load the  date and time. The console show this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>   jquery.datetimepicker.js:1619(anonymous function)

This is my code:

```
<div class="contact">
                    <div class="company_address">

                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-form" >
                        {{ form(form) }}
                        <button type="submit" class="cancel" name="cancel" onclick="location.href = '{{ path('assistance_list') }}'">Cancel</button>

                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {

                            $.datetimepicker.setLocale('en');

                            $("#daiquiri_daiquiribundle_assistance_date input").each(function () {
                                $(this).attr("readonly", "readonly");
                            });

                            $('#daiquiri_daiquiribundle_assistance_date_date').datetimepicker({
                                format: "Y-m-d",
                                timepicker: false,
                                datepicker: true,
                                theme: 'dark'
                            });
                            $('#daiquiri_daiquiribundle_assistance_date_time').datetimepicker({
                                format: "H:i",
                                timepicker: true,
                                datepicker: false,
                                step: 10,
                                theme: 'dark'
                            });

                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
```

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery UI Datepicker? `datetimepicker` depends on it.

Comment: where is this `daiquiri_daiquiribundle_assistance_date_date`

Comment: This is the id of the input where I want to load the datetimepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this question, It is my error I am trying to load :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

When it should load:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
*<script src="jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>*
```

With this change solved the problem.
Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using said function name that you KNOW is a jQuery method name, and this error is returned, it is 100% a typo on your behalf, or the jQuery library is not loaded correctly. Since the document ready works, but not this method, that says jQuery is loaded correctly, but not the source library for the datetimepicker method. If you are in chrome, hit F12, and then check your resources or console. The console should say something along the lines of "Failed to load resource" if you have a link to it, but it is incorrect. If you have not loaded it at all, the library you need for those plugins are here: https://jqueryui.com/